# pysimplegui -button for scrolling all the way down

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm building a gui using pysimplegui which contains lots of input boxes as shown bellow:

[image]

In order to give the user a comfortable navigation experience I have added the buttons Down and Up which their purpose is move the scroll all the way down or up according to the pressed button:

```
form = sg.Window('analysis').Layout([
                            [sg.Column(layout, size=(width / 3, height / 2), scrollable=True, key = "Column")], 
                            [sg.OK(), sg.Button('Up', key = "up"), sg.Button('Down', key = "down")]
                                ])
```

This code is basically creating The window with a column element inside with a pre created layout (containing all of the input boxes inside), a size with pre created sizes, scorllable enabled and a key which I want to use to control the scroller location.

The other row contains all of the discussed buttons.

after wards I have created a loop to manage all the events when triggered:

```
while True:
event, values = form.read()

if(event == sg.WIN_CLOSED):
    break
elif(event == "down"):
    form.Element('Column').set_vscroll_position(1.0)
elif(enent == "up"):
    form.Element('Column').set_vscroll_position(0.0)
```

The buttons did not act according to the plan and when triggered a warning jumped up:

> Warning setting the vertical scroll (yview_moveto failed)
> 'TkScrollableFrame' object has no attribute 'yview_moveto

It seems like I did everything according to the documentation of pysimplegui but it doesn't work.
Any help will be appreciated.

thanks, with respect, revolution.

Operating system: Windows 10
Python version: 3.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting pysimplegui and other contributors via github the explanation for the warnings was the following:

> Columns are special and will need some additional code done in order to manipulate their scrollbars. Didn't think to document / handle this element. The code operates on the "Widget" and the Column element on its own isn't a standalone Widget like some of the others with scrollbars.

more over a solution was offered in the form of tkinter calls and trates:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ('Courier New', 16)
text = '\n'.join(chr(i)*50 for i in range(65, 91))
column = [[sg.Text(text, font=font)]]

layout = [
    [sg.Column(column, size=(800, 300), scrollable=True, key = "Column")],
    [sg.OK(), sg.Button('Up', key = "up"), sg.Button('Down', key = "down")],
]

window = sg.Window('Demo', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "down":
        window['Column'].Widget.canvas.yview_moveto(1.0)
    elif event == "up":
        window['Column'].Widget.canvas.yview_moveto(0.0)

window.close()
```

Comment: it worked. Here is the link for the thread: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/3320