# Can PySimpleGUI table element be automatically scrolled to the bottom?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a table with 10 displayed rows, however often there will be more records. They are sorted with the newest at the bottom.

```
        [sg.Table(values=data_values, headings=data_headings,
                        max_col_width=65,
                        auto_size_columns=True,
                        select_mode=sg.TABLE_SELECT_MODE_BROWSE,
                        justification='left',
                        enable_events=True,
                        num_rows=10, key='_tracker_')]
```

By default the scroll is at the top. Can I automatically scroll it to the bottom.

I know the multiline element has and autoscroll attribute, but it is not available for the table.

Comment: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/1878#issuecomment-645316550  sounds like `myTable.yview_moveto(1)` might work :/

Comment: Method `set_vscroll_position(percent_from_top)` set the vertical scroll postition for an element's Widget. Value `0` for top, and `1.0` for bottom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pysimplegui -button for scrolling all the way down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63506070/pysimplegui-button-for-scrolling-all-the-way-down)